# AM and PM values of calendar wrong at 12?

Tags: java, android

Below is code that I am using to move a date back a 3 hours. It displays the new time and also am pm value. But when it gets to 12pm or am it changes the am pm value of the new time to the same as the 12 it came from. Ie if it is set at 12am and the new value is 9pm it outputs 9pm. Am I missing something simple? Am I thinking about this correctly that 12am is midnight as the such?

```
         calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, HourValue);
         calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, MinValue);
         calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
         if(AMPM.equals("AM")){ampmval=0;}
         else{ampmval=1;}
         Log.e("AMPMVAL Before",Integer.toString(ampmval));

         sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh");
         NewHourValue = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
         Log.e("Before Time",NewHourValue);

         calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, ampmval);
         calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -300);

         int AmOrPm = calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
         Log.e("AMPMVAL After",Integer.toString(AmOrPm)); 
         sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh");
         NewHourValue = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
         Log.e("After Time",NewHourValue);
```

This outputs something like

```
05-15 23:07:11.233: E/Before Time(457):   09:00:00 PM
05-15 23:07:11.240: E/AMPMVAL After(457): 0
05-15 23:07:11.640: E/After Time(457):    06:00:00 AM
05-15 23:07:23.369: E/AMPMVAL Before(457):0
05-15 23:07:23.742: E/Before Time(457):   10:00:00 PM
05-15 23:07:23.749: E/AMPMVAL After(457): 0
05-15 23:07:24.113: E/After Time(457):    07:00:00 AM
05-15 23:07:28.320: E/AMPMVAL Before(457):0
05-15 23:07:28.712: E/Before Time(457):   11:00:00 PM
05-15 23:07:28.720: E/AMPMVAL After(457): 0
05-15 23:07:29.112: E/After Time(457):    08:00:00 AM
05-15 23:07:34.700: E/AMPMVAL Before(457):1
05-15 23:07:35.300: E/Before Time(457):   12:00:00 AM
05-15 23:07:35.330: E/AMPMVAL After(457): 1
05-15 23:07:35.693: E/After Time(457):    09:00:00 PM
```

As you can see it works fine as I increment through the hours before 12am (Midnight) but when it gets to midnight it then says that the new value is also in am

Comment: I think you're doing yourself a disservice by printing only _portions_ of the time; can you get the output complete with minutes, seconds, and _24 hour time_ to unambiguously show you the hours?

Comment: Yeah I can. I shall do that and report back

Comment: @sarnold I've run the advice and it is a little strange the results it has provided.

Comment: Definitely strange, feels like `Calendar.AM_PM` can't be trusted.

Comment: Noon and midnight are not “AM” or “PM”. “AM” is “ante-meridian” (before noon), while “PM” is “post-meridian” (after noon), so by definition noon itself cannot be before or after noon. Midnight is 12 M (midnight).

Comment: @Lawrence what you are saying sounds confusing. If am means before noon; shouldnt time decrease before noon and increase after noon? {11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,noon,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}

Answer (score 2):

What HOUR value you use for midnight/noon? 0 and 12 are not same.

E.g for midnight you have to set `AM_PM` to `AM` and `HOUR` to 0 (not 12). `DateFormat` output in AM/PM format will show 12 AM on midnight.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to show exact hour string in Calendar Object initialize df object as given below::

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Then the date string 2012-05-19 12:00:00 when converted to Calendar object will have Hour as 12 not 0.

But of your are using Date Format as

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

then 12 will be converted to 0 in hour

Comment: But how to make 12 midnight be 12 pm

Answer (score 0):

Just set hour to 0. Everything else can remain the same and it will work fine. In the Java Calendar api, it is even said that "Noon and midnight are represented by 0, not by 12"